# li background color gives children the same color

Tags: html, css

I have some css that makes lists look like a treeview. I'm trying to change the background of the currently selected li but it also changes all it's children to that background color too. Is there a way to not have this happen?

Here is the base tree structure in which I then fill in via code ulScripts and ulShaders from reading a folder structure. For testing I just made the Scripts li background gray and when the other li's are loaded they all have gray as well.

```
<div class="css-treeview" id="projectTree" style="display: none;">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="projectRoot" /><label for="ProjectRoot" id="projectRootLabel">ProjectName</label>
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="Scripts" /><label for="Scripts">Scripts</label>
                            <ul id="ulScripts">
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="Shaders" /><label for="Shaders">Shaders</label>
                            <ul id="ulShaders">
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Jquery to select the li

```
$(".css-treeview li").each(function(){
                $(this).click(function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color", "gray");
                });
            });
```

Treeview css in which I'd also love to change it so if you click the label a dbl click is required to expand it vs a single like it is now. The checkbox part would still be a single click

```
/*
 * CSS3 Treeview. No JavaScript
 * @version 1.0
 * @author Martin Ivanov
 * @url developer's website: http://wemakesites.net/
 * @url developer's twitter: https://twitter.com/#!/wemakesitesnet
 * @url developer's blog http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/
 **/

/*
 * This solution works with all modern browsers and Internet Explorer 9+. 
 * If you are interested in purchasing a JavaScript enabler for IE8 
 * for the CSS3 Treeview, please, check this link:
 * http://experiments.wemakesites.net/miscellaneous/acidjs-css3-treeview/
 **/

.css-treeview ul,
.css-treeview li
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.css-treeview input
{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

.css-treeview
{
    font: normal 11px "Segoe UI", Arial, Sans-serif;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.css-treeview a
{
    color: #00f;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.css-treeview a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.css-treeview input + label + ul
{
    margin: 0 0 0 22px;
}

.css-treeview input ~ ul
{
    display: none;
}

.css-treeview label,
.css-treeview label::before
{
    cursor: default;
}

.css-treeview input:disabled + label
{
    cursor: default;
    opacity: .6;
}

.css-treeview input:checked:not(:disabled) ~ ul
{
    display: block;
}

.css-treeview label,
.css-treeview label::before
{
    background: url("../img/icons.png") no-repeat;
}

.css-treeview label,
.css-treeview a,
.css-treeview label::before
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.css-treeview label
{
    background-position: 18px 0;
}

.css-treeview label::before
{
    content: "";
    width: 16px;
    margin: 0 22px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}

.css-treeview input:checked + label::before
{
    background-position: 0 -16px;
}

/* webkit adjacent element selector bugfix */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{
    .css-treeview 
    {
        -webkit-animation: webkit-adjacent-element-selector-bugfix infinite 1s;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes webkit-adjacent-element-selector-bugfix 
    {
        from 
        { 
            padding: 0;
        } 
        to 
        { 
            padding: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your css please so we can troubleshoot?

Comment: And javascript if you are using any.

Comment: At a quick glance though, anything within that LI will have a background of gray, since it's contained within the element. You can always target the child UL to change its colours.

Comment: _“but it also changes all it's children to that background color too”_ – no, it shouldn’t; `background-color` is not inherited. Of course you will _see_ the background of the parent element “shine through” all descendant elements that don’t have their own background set.

Comment: So on each click would I have to set all backgrounds to white, then set only the 1 that was clicked to gray? Is that an efficient way to handle this or is there a better way?